# Javascript Object Literal, Cannot Set Properties

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I am trying to add elements to my object literal and all I receive are `undefined` outputs in the console.

Why is itemSize being printed as `undefined` and why, as a consequence, are all the properties I am trying to set also undefined. I must be missing something big here.

I also don't understand the purpose of `get testFunction` and how it is even accessed since it doesn't seem to be following the signature of other functions which have a colon after the function name.

I'm so confused at the moment.

**index.html**

```
var square = new GULE.Scene();
square.hey( 5 );
```

**gule.js**

```
 var GULE = GULE || {};

 GULE.Scene = function ( itemSize ) {

  this.itemSize = itemSize;
  console.log( "Trying in constructor: " + this.itemSize );
  console.log( "Passed variable: " + itemSize );

 };

 GULE.Scene.prototype = {

      constructor: GULE.Scene,
      stuff: 1,
      get testFunction () {
            console.log( "testFunction!" );
          },
      add: function () {
              this.stuff += 1;
            },
      hey: function () {
              console.log( this.stuff );
              console.log( "Trying in function: " + this.itemSize );
           }
 };
```

Comment: because you are not passing any value to the function.should be new GULE.Scene(<item-size-here>);

Comment: Oh my god. Well now that that blunder is out of the way, what is the purpose of the `get testFunction`, I don't understand how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is itemSize being printed as undefined...?

Because you're not passing anything into the `Scene` constructor, so the argument is `undefined`, which is what you're assigning to `itemSize`.

> what is the purpose of the `get testFunction`...?

It creates a property called `testFunction` that, when accessed, calls a function; see [§11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) of the spec. It's an ES5 feature. If open your web console and then do this after creating your `square`:

```
var x = square.testFunction;
```

...you'll see "testFunction!" in the console, because you accessed the property.

The reason you see `undefined` when you read `testFunction` is that the function defined by the getter doesn't return anything.

Here's a clearer example:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  
  var obj = (function() {
    var propValue = "Initial value";
    
    return {
      normalProp: 42,
      get accessorProp() {
        display("Reading accessorProp");
        return propValue;
      },
      set accessorProp(value) {
        display("Writing accessorProp, new value: " + value);
        propValue = value;
      }
    };
  })();
  
  display("normalProp is " + obj.normalProp);
  display("accessorProp is " + obj.accessorProp);
  obj.accessorProp = "Testing";
  display("accessorProp is now " + obj.accessorProp);

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

The right code should be -
`var square = new GULE.Scene(5);
square.hey(  );`

Comment: mistake -`getTestFunction  : function() {
            console.log( "testFunction!" );
          },`

Comment: No, it's not a mistake, it's a feature of JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry about that, its so rarely used that we skip it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get